# Qual é a diferença entre array_walk e array_map?

Tags: php, array

No PHP, temos duas funções que percorrem o array e aplica uma função determinada para cada elemento: array_walk e array_map.

Exemplo:

```
$meu_array = array(1, 2, 3);

$callback = function ($value)
{
     return $value * 2;
};

$novo_array = array_map($callback, $meu_array);

var_dump($novo_array);
```

Saída:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 6
```

Exemplo 2:

```
$novo_array = $meu_array;

$callback = function (&$value)
{
    $value *= 2;
};


array_walk($novo_array, $callback);

var_dump($novo_array);
```

Saída:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 6
```

Além do fato de que uma use passagem por referência e outra não, parece que no final das contas as duas fazem a mesma coisa.

Sendo assim:

- Existe alguma diferença entre `array_map` e `array_walk` - desconsiderando as diferenças já citadas?
- Quando é recomendado utilizar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Além de um utilizar referencia e outro retornar um novo array, veja a assinatura de ambos os métodos:

```
bool array_walk ( array &$array , callable $callback [, mixed $userdata = NULL ] )

array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

Ao utilizar o `array_walk` podemos fornecer para a função `callback` argumentos extras. O `array_walk` permite trabalhar com as chaves do array também:

```
<?php

function mergeValueKey(&$value, $key, $prefix = '')
{
    $value = $prefix . $value . $key;
}

$array = [
    't1' => 'Teste1 ',
    't2' => 'Teste2 ',
    't3' => 'Teste3 ',
];

array_walk($array, 'mergeValueKey');

var_dump($array);
```

Resultado com `array_walk`:

```
array(3) {
  ["t1"]=>
  string(9) "t1Teste1 "
  ["t2"]=>
  string(9) "t2Teste2 "
  ["t3"]=>
  string(9) "t3Teste3 "
}
```